# to make accordion as a checkbox

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, bootstrap-4, accordion

[image]In my angular application, I am using bootstrap accordion.

But I want accordion to act as a  check box, if the check box is checked the accordion should expand and get selected.

But I am not able to do it. I have tried everything.

Here is the code:

```
 <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Solid header accordion</h4>
        <p class="card-description">Use class <code>.accordion-solid-header</code> for basic accordion</p>
        <div class="mt-4">
          <ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="collapse-12" class="accordion-solid-header">
            <ngb-panel id="collapse-10" title="How can I pay for an order I placed?">
 <input type="checkbox" class="col-lg-3 pull-right" id="16" value="{{i.challengeId}}"
            name="challenge" formControlName="challenge" (change)="handleSelected(i)" />
              <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="assets/images/samples/300x300/10.jpg" class="mw-100"/>                              
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-9">
                    You can pay for the product you have purchased using credit cards, debit cards, or via online banking. 
                    We also provide cash-on-delivery services.                             
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ng-template>
            </ngb-panel>
            <ngb-panel id="collapse-11" title="I can’t sign in to my account">
 <input type="checkbox" class="col-lg-3 pull-right" id="16" value="{{i.challengeId}}"
            name="challenge" formControlName="challenge" (change)="handleSelected(i)" />
              <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                If while signing in to your account you see an error message, you can do the following
                <ol class="pl-3 mt-4">
                  <li>Check your network connection and try again</li>
                  <li>Make sure your account credentials are correct while signing in</li>
                  <li>Check whether your account is accessible in your region</li>
                </ol>
                <br>
                <p class="text-success">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-alert-octagon mr-2"></i>If the problem persists, you can contact our support.
                </p>
              </ng-template>
            </ngb-panel>
            <ngb-panel id="collapse-12" title="Can I add money to the wallet?">
 <input type="checkbox" class="col-lg-3 pull-right" id="16" value="{{i.challengeId}}"
            name="challenge" formControlName="challenge" (change)="handleSelected(i)" />
              <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                  You can add money to the wallet for any future transaction from your bank account using net-banking, or credit/debit card transaction. The money in the wallet can be used for an easier and faster transaction.                
              </ng-template>
            </ngb-panel>
          </ngb-accordion>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you post a picture of how this looks? Not sure I am following.

Comment: I have added a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the prettiest solution, but to make this work I added the checkbox to the header and listened to the ngModelChange event from each checkbox, basically:

```
<input
      class="form-check-input"
      type="checkbox"
      [ngModel]="checked1"
      (ngModelChange)="modelChanged(0, $event, acc)"
      id="check1"
    />
```

and I reset the models and set for each input

```
public modelChanged(pos, event, acc) {
  this.checked = [false, false, false];
  this.checked[pos] = event;
  event ? acc.expand(`toggle-${pos + 1}`) : acc.collapse(`toggle-${pos + 1}`);
}
```

I created this stackblitz to show it working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spgmuk?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccordion-static.html

**EDIT:**

To open the panels initially you use the input property activeIds ([apidocs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api))

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" [activeIds]="initialIds" [closeOthers]="true">

...

public initialIds = ['toggle-3'];
```

Comment: Thanks the solution is working for me.
I have one more question that if the value of ngmodel is checked true from the ts file, then the check box is coming selected but the accorsion is not coming opened, can you please provide a solution for this issue as well.
Thanks

Comment: Updated the stackBlitz with the initial panels